# Creating a Menu-Based Program

Tags: programming

I want to make a program that basically displays a menu, and that menu leads to smaller menus, until it gets to pages of info. I know that a website would work better, however, I want this to be able to work offline. I don't know what kind of program to start with, so if someone could give me an idea of a few, that would be great!

Comment: if you think html-pages will be the best, why you don't use html-pages? they don't have to be used online via a http-server. - i know a view user-manuals/info-projects which are written in html and published for offline use. (as a side effect you can use the same code online, but only have to maintain one code-base and serve every time the latest version.)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [Zim](http://www.zim-wiki.org/) which is desktop wiki application.  It's written in Python, so it can be used on most computers with the relevant dependencies installed, and has support for Windows, Ubuntu and others ready.

Answer (score 1):

[WikidPad](http://wikidpad.sourceforge.net/) Is long living open sourced project that runs on Windows/Linux/Mac OS

You can create hierarchy tree like menus

[image: WikidPad]